# Unresolved reference: Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create a simple counter app with some images. I am trying to create a spinner which includes different items. I was using this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spinner-in-kotlin/ to try create it but then i got this error:[image]

Here that part of the code:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.drop_1)
if (spinner != null) {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lands)
    spinner.adapter = adapter}
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var health : TextView
    private lateinit var plus : Button
    private lateinit var minus : Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var hp = 20
        val lands = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Lands)

        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.drop_1)
        if (spinner != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lands)
            spinner.adapter = adapter}

        health = findViewById(R.id.textView_health)
        plus = findViewById(R.id.button_plus)
        minus = findViewById(R.id.button_minus)


        plus.setOnClickListener {
            hp += 1
            health.text = hp.toString()
        }
        minus.setOnClickListener {
            if (hp > 1) {
                hp -= 1
                health.text = hp.toString()}
            else{
                health.text = "You lose!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `import android.widget.ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: plz, share your full Activity code.

Comment: @Fureeish i didn't import it but now i did and its working thanks. :)